# Cannot read property 'task' of undefined

Tags: javascript, body-parser

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzyXs.png)I never faced this problem before but now "req.body.task" is not working and I don't know why its happening.

**Here's the form**

```
<form action="/" method="POST">
    <div class="input-box">
        <input type="text" name="task" id=""  class="input-add">
        <button type="submit" name="button" class="btn-add">+</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Here's the post request**

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");

const app = express();
app.set(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

app.use(express.static("public"));

let items = [];

app.get("/", (req,res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

app.post("/", (req,res) => {
    const item = req.body.task;
    console.log(item);
    
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Server running at port 3000");
    
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
app.set(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
```

should be

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
```

BodyParser is a middleware and should be used using `app.use` methods.
See the [docs](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html) for more details

`app.set` is used to set values to app variables, for example view engines